# Store enum as comma separated list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying to save an `enum` as a comma-separated list in a DB.

I know I can do something like this to actually store a comma separated list:

```
part.MyProperty = new[] {"foo", "bar"};
```

and the DB would have an entry "foo, bar".

What I don't know how to do is how to store an `enum`, such as:

```
public enum Choices { Choice1, Choice2, Choice3 }
```

I gather I have to use `Parse` and `ToString` to use the `enum` values, but I am not sure how to do it.

This doesn't seem right:

```
part.MyProperty = new[] return from name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T))
   let enumValue = Convert.ToString((T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name, true))
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please be aware storing multiple values in a column violates [First normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's wrong with `part.MyProperty = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Choices));` ?

To get a comma separated list, use `String.Join`:

```
string csvEnums = string.Join(",", Enum.GetNames(typeof(Choices)));
```

Comment: where is the string getting called though - sorry, bit of a n00b

Comment: @REMESQ: Sorry, i dont understand your question. I must admit that i'm not even sure why you have used Linq to get this value or how you want to store this in the database.

Comment: @REMESQ, Enum.GetNames() returns a collection of string

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Join(",", Enum.GetNames(typeof(Choices)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can build your own utitlity method that will get enums name in more nice syntax:

```
public static TEnum[] GetEnumValues<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct { 
   return (TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)); 
}
```

and then:

```
Choices[] choices = GetEnumValues<Choices>();
```

or
    `part.MyProperty = GetEnumValues<Choices>().Select(n=>n.ToString()).ToArray()`;

Answer (score 0):

```
[Flags]
public enum Choices { 
   Choice1 = 1, 
   Choice2 = 2, 
   Choice3 = 4 
}

Choices a = Choices.Choice1 | Choices.Choice3;

Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
```

outputs: `Choice1, Choice3`